# Does the shell fork when I use built-in commands?

Tags: shell, io-redirection

When I run the command `type type`, this gives me a result to standard output.

So, now I try this command:

```
type type > abc.txt
```

It redirects the standard output to `abc.txt`. So, if this command executes on the same process (bash itself), then file descriptor 1 points to `abc.txt`. 
After that, whenever I use run a command, these results should go to file `abc.txt`, because file descriptor 1 points to `abc.txt`.

However, results always go to standard output. Does this mean that shell built-ins run under a forked process?

Comment: I've proposed an edit to your question to make it easier to read. Hopefully, this is alright with you :D

Comment: The basic answer is 'no'. Consider `cd`. If it executed in a child process it would have no effect. Indeed very early in the piece it *did* execute in a child process, leading to much bewilderment among the UNIX developers ... until they twigged that some commands had to be built-in and executed in the current shell process.

Answer (score 10, accepted):

#### Output redirection

File descriptor `1` represents `stdout`, the standard output stream. When output redirection is used in `type type > abc.txt`, the shell opens the file `abc.txt` for writing and the file descriptor `1` is modified so that it points to the open file instead of the terminal device.

However, this redirection only applies to the **current command** being executed so this does *not* imply that the command executes in a forked process (or subshell).

#### Persistent redirection

If you wanted the redirection to persist, you could use the `exec` shell builtin to modify the file descriptors, e.g., to redirect standard output for successive commands, run the following command.

```
exec >abc.txt
```

Be careful running this as your shell session will be hard to use if all
command output is being redirected to a file instead of your terminal device. You can restore the `stdout` file descriptor to the terminal output device by redirecting it to the same device pointed to by `stderr` (file descriptor `2`):

```
exec >&2
```

#### Related resources

For more details, see:

- the section on [Redirections](https://www.gnu.org/software/bash/manual/html_node/Redirections.html) from the Bash manual
- [Input And Output](http://mywiki.wooledge.org/BashGuide/InputAndOutput) from Greg’s Wiki
- [Redirection tutorial](http://wiki.bash-hackers.org/howto/redirection_tutorial) from Bash-hackers Wiki
- the [Redirection](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Redirection_%28computing%29) Wikipedia article
- the [file descriptor](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/File_descriptor) Wikipedia article

Answer (score 20):

You're right in that normally, to redirect a command, all the shell has to do is fork a child process, do the redirection in the child only (the parent file descriptors are not affected) and then execute the command in there (while the parent just waits for the child).

For builtin commands (or compound commands, or functions...), there is no fork nor exec. Yet after a redirected builtin command terminates, the file descriptors are back to how they were before.

To do that, the shell just saves a copy of the redirected file descriptor to another file descriptor before doing the redirection, marks that file descriptor with the O_CLOEXEC flag (in case the builtin ends up executing a command like `eval` or `command` would), and when the builtin returns, the shell restores the file descriptor.

You can see that if you run for instance:

```
strace sh -c 'echo test > /dev/null; :'
```

You'll see (only relevant entries included):

- `open("/dev/null", O_WRONLY|O_CREAT|O_TRUNC, 0666) = 3`: opens the file to redirect to.
- `fcntl(1, F_DUPFD, 10)          = 10`: duplicate the original stdout to the first available fd >= 10 (here 10).
- `fcntl(10, F_SETFD, FD_CLOEXEC) = 0`: set the O_CLOEXEC flag on it
- `dup2(3, 1)                     = 1`: make the redirected file stdout
- `close(3)                       = 0`: no longer needed
- `write(1, "test\n", 5)          = 5`: echo runs and writes "test\n" on its stdout (now redirected to /dev/null).
- `dup2(10, 1)                    = 1`: restore stdout
- `close(10)                      = 0`: close fd 10 no longer needed.

Note that in the Bourne shell, redirecting a compound command did cause a fork (as in `a=0; { a=1; echo "$a"; } >&2; echo "$a"` would give you `1` then `0`). To work around that, you actually had to do the above by hand:

Instead of

```
while cmd1; do cmd2; i=`expr "$i" + 1`; done > file
```

You had to do:

```
exec 3>&1 > file
while cmd1 3>&-; do cmd2 3>&-; i=`expr "$i" + 1 3>&-`; done
exec >&3 3>&-
```

(with a `3>&-` for each command as that fd doesn't have the O_CLOEXEC flag).

And in early versions of the Bourne shell, you could not redirect builtins. On a Unix V7 on an emulated pdp11:

```
$ eval a=1 > /tmp/x
illegal io
$ read a < /etc/passwd
illegal io
```

Answer (score 0):

As soon as the command completes the input files is closed, making it available for writing by other processes, file descriptor is released, and the child process terminated.